# Were changes to the attributes of the AppData folder made in Windows 10 to hide it from Windows Explorer - even when hidden files/folders are enabled?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, home-folder, appdata

If choosing to show hidden files/folders from within the Folder Options of Windows Explorer in Windows 10, I've noticed that the "AppData" folder within "C:\Users\Username" isn't displayed as it was in Windows 7 - it's possible to manually add "AppData" to the end of the Address Bar, however. Were changes to the attributes of this folder made in Win 10 so that it's not displayed by default?

Comment: Show Hidden toggles AppData for me, on 2004. I'd wondered whether it could be 'protected system' but that reveals the other link to 'application data' not the regular appdata.

Comment: I also don't share your experience on Windows 10 2004. AppData is just a hidden folder.